# NullPointer Exception - JSF Event Handling ( ValueChangeListener )

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, xhtml, jsf-2.2

I am learning JSF Event Handling and when I try to run some sample code, I am getting a Null Pointer Exception.

This is my **index.xhtml** snippet,

```
<h:form>
            <h2>Implement valueChangeListener</h2>
            <hr />
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                Selected Locale:
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{userData.selectedCountry}" onchange="submit()">
                    <f:valueChangeListener type="com.cyb3rh4wk.test.LocaleChangeListener" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{userData.countries}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                Country Name:
                <h:outputText id="countryInterface" value="#{userData.selectedCountry}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

**UserData.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userData", eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserData implements Serializable{
    private static Map<String, String> countryMap;
    private String selectedCountry = "United Kingdom";
    static  {
        countryMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        countryMap.put("en", "United Kingdon");
        countryMap.put("fr", "French");
        countryMap.put("de", "German");
        countryMap.put("def", "Default");
    }  
    public String getSelectedCountry() {
        return selectedCountry;
    }
    public void setSelectedCountry(String selectedCountry) {
        this.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
        System.out.println("Locale set");
    }    
    public Map<String, String> getCountries() {
        return countryMap;
    }        
    public void localeChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        selectedCountry = event.getNewValue().toString();
    }        
}
```

**LocaleChangeListener.java**

```
public class LocaleChangeListener implements ValueChangeListener    {
    @Override
    public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        UserData userData = (UserData) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("userData");
        String newLocale = event.getNewValue().toString();
        if (newLocale != null)
            userData.setSelectedCountry(newLocale);
        else
            userData.setSelectedCountry("Default");   
    } 
}
```

When I run these on Glassfish Server, I get an **error**,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cyb3rh4wk.test.LocaleChangeListener.processValueChange(LocaleChangeListener.java:25)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ValueChangeListenerHandler$LazyValueChangeListener.processValueChange(ValueChangeListenerHandler.java:128)
    at javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent.processListener(ValueChangeEvent.java:134)
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Have you checked that `userData` is not null?

Comment: After checking, I got userData as null but still "Locale set" is printed when I catch the exception and print error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are getting `NullPointerException` because `userData` is not found in the session scope.
2. The reason this is happening is that you put the `userData` in the application scope (`@ApplicationScoped` annotation on your managed bean) and searching it in the session scope.
3. Eventhough you verified that `userData` is null it still prints `Locale set` because the bean is in the application scope as described in `2.` above.
4. So what is the solution? Either change `@ApplicationScoped` to `@SessionScoped` or access your `userData` by changing:

   ```
   UserData userData = (UserData) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("userData");
   ```

to

```
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UserData userData = (UserData)ctx.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("userData");
```